# ionicframework iOS cannot be uploaded after push notifications were added

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, capacitor

I have recently deployed iOS app (using ionic framework + capacitor) to the app store.
Today I have added push notifications support, using this guide: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase

I have tested the app - push notifications works for the connected device.
Now, I want to update my application in the app store.
I've updated the version, made "Archive".
Now if I press Validate App - everything is good. App is validated.
When I try to distribute the app (upload) - it throws an error, during the upload process:

```
App Store Connect Operation Error

The app references non-public selectors in Payload/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: applicationNameForUserAgent, initWithFrame:configuration:, isMainFrame, setNavigationDelegate:, targetFrame With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.50 for id f0321e79-36f4-456c-a1b3-92d2be0d7d12
```

Why happens like so? How should I fix the problem, keeping the push notifications support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an validation error Apple's backend.
It's already fixed now.

More info here: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5661